# how to record audio for specific of time until some action(like keyboard press) in Python sounddevice?

Tags: python, audio, python-sounddevice

I'm very new to Python,so I have small projet to get use to know more about Python, my project is simple, just recording audio use `sounddevice` but problem is , in documentary, it only record if have static seconds like code sample code below,and i have no idea how to stop or pause recording,in my case is press a key, like "enter to stop, shift to pause"

```
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf
import time
def sync_record(filename, duration, fs, channels):
   print('recording')
   myrecording = sd.rec(int(duration * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=channels)
   sd.wait()
   sf.write(filename, myrecording, fs)
   print('done recording')
# playback file
sync_record('sync_record.wav', 10, 16000, 1)
```

so my question is, how can i pause and record audio with no duration required, and how to stop and pause that use `sounddevice`, thank you guys a lot

Comment: Please be more specific. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

```
print "* record until keypress"
from openexp.keyboard import keyboard
# Short timeout so get_key() doesn't block
my_keyboard = keyboard(exp, timeout=2)
all = []
while my_keyboard.get_key()[0] == None: # Loop until a key has been pressed
    data = stream.read(chunk) # Record data
    all.append(data) # Add the data to a buffer (a list of chunks)
print "* done recording"
```

This illustrates how you could stream data till a key is pressed.

```
import keyboard
k = keyboard.read_key()  # in my python interpreter, this captures "enter up"
k = keyboard.read_key()  # so repeat the line if in the python interpreter
```

Use the same logic with your code. So that the recording stops once the user presses a key.

Comment: thank you a lot, i will try it right now, and report as soon as possible, hope you help me deal with it

Comment: but i still don't get it , what is '``while my_keyboard.get_key()[0] == None`` bro?

Comment: it just loops until a key has been pressed.

Comment: Please note that `stream.read(...)` returns two things, see https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.14/api.html#sounddevice.Stream.read.